# ZPanel on Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2

I have configured Ubuntu Server 13.10 with apache2, php, mysql and phpmyadmin.

I want to install zPanelcp for managing server for hosting purpose but my question is this should i need to install zpanelcp on fresh ubuntu without apache2, php, mysql and phpmyadmin or after installation of apache2, php, mysql and phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Fresh install of the OS with minimal options. The following modules MUST NOT be installed on your server:

```
MySql
Apache
Bind

Dovecot (Ubuntu, CentOS)
Postfix (Ubuntu, CentOS)
proFTPd (Ubuntu, CentOS)

hMail Server (Windows)
FileZilla Server (Windows)
IIS (Windows)
```

See: http://docs.zpanelcp.com/?node=22

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support Ubuntu 13.10 yet.

> ZPanel won't work on any Ubuntu version that isn't 12.04LTS unfortunately.
>   12.10 Uses PHP 5.4. (Suhosin support was dropped (integrated) in that version). ZPanel relies heavily on suhosin so just that one package makes it usable on any other version of Ubuntu.
>   I'm pretty sure that there wouldn't be any conflicting dependencies on a desktop version.
>   Might I suggest that if you're dead set on using 13.10 then run a virtual environment of 12.04 and SSH into it for website access.

It's mentioned on there official forum:

http://forums.zpanelcp.com/thread-9501.html

Answer (score 0):

I have ZpanelCP version 10.1.0 working in an ubuntu 13 box and don't have any problem.

[image]

According to their documentation, you should not install those modules as stated before by Hilmi Erdem KEREN